# Azure API Management - Dev Portal: Display Product level policies on Operation View?

Tags: azure, documentation-generation, azure-api-management

We've recently started a project whereby we have a set of REST APIs running through Azure's API Management portal (AAPIM) which then routes them to our backend system.

We have some policies which apply to all operations (basically security headers) so rather than applying them to each operation, we've applied them at the Product level, which makes sense logically and seems to work when AAPIM handles the REST requests.

However, the issue is that product level policies don't get pulled through onto the operations page therefore it doesn't really show developers the full requirements of the operation. 
This also means that "Try it" doesn't include the headers so the developer needs to manually add them in (which obviously isn't ideal).

My expectation would be that the policies would cascade down through the levels on the Developer Portal as they do when handling requests?
I've had a read of the Developer Portal documentation around updating the page templates and the data which is available but to no avail.
For example, the product object doesn't seem to have the relevant properties which the operation uses to output the policies.
Thinking about it, policies like these set at the product level don't get displayed anywhere on the developer portal.
The same occurs when applying at the "All APIs" level.

Am I missing something or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

In APIM policies are considered to be part of implementation detail of your API and thus do not affect in any way how your API is presented in Dev Portal. The only thing that matters for Dev Portal is API/Operation specification. Currently there is no way to declare common headers for Operations at API level, the only supported way is inside Operation specification. So you will have to add that information to each Operation. If there are a lot of them using Open API Specification view in Azure Portal may help as it allows you to edit API as a whole and you can copy things around there. Or you could automate it via API.